# How to use flask's @login_required

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

My login authentication is working fine using Flask and MySQL (im not using FlaskSqlAlchemy) **i have been able to login and out!** but I've been trying to implement a logic of  "if this user is successfully logged in let them have access to this endpoint"  and something is wrong.

this is the error I get when trying to access employees endpoint after loggin in (which returns me 200):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2023 13:23:00] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2023 13:23:04] "GET /employees HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2023 13:23:04] "GET /login?next=/employees HTTP/1.1" 415 -
```

postman says this:

```
  <html lang=en>
    <title>415 Unsupported Media Type</title>
    <h1>Unsupported Media Type</h1>
    <p>Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 
    &#39;application/json&#39;.</p>
```

my request is a GET in  --> http://127.0.0.1:5000/employees

the code looks like this:

```
@employees_bp.route('/employees', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_all():
    get all employees logic here
```

my app.py:

```
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login.login'
```

my login:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    code here (i cant put much here)


@login_bp.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
   code here (i cant put much here)
```

if theres any more code that is needed to understand this error please let me know and I'll put it here (and sorry in advance!)

Comment: The Flask dev server does not understand the Content-Type of the request you are making. You can specify  Content-Type in postman, eg. `application/json` etc